# Why can't we add brackets for functions in dispatch method table - Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, oop, dispatch

I am trying to understand the design of dispatch table in function tables.

Here is what I initially coded

```
class Aave():
    def __init__(self,address):
        self.address = address
    def function_map(self):
        mapping = {1:self.test(),2:self.test2()}
        print(type(self.test()))
        return mapping[self.address]()
    
    def test(self):
        print(1)
        return 1
    
    def test2(self):
        print(2)
        return 2
a = Aave(1)
print(a.function_map())
```

However, this function would call the 2 function `self.test()` and `self.test2()` instead of just the function associated with key `self.test()`.

On the other hand, coding the dispatch table without brackets would perform the specified mapped function

like as such

```
    def function_map(self):
        mapping = {1:self.test,2:self.test2}
        print(type(self.test()))
        return mapping[self.address]()
```

I have referred to different resources trying to understand, but they don't explain the difference in behaviour.

I was wondering if anyone could provide some enlightenment regarding this issue.

Referred to:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch01s07.html

https://betterprogramming.pub/dispatch-tables-in-python-d37bcc443b0b

Comment: I think what you need is ```mapping = {1:self.test, 2:self.test2}```

Comment: yup, i tried that and it works. why do you think that's the case? @ewong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the issue, let's read the code as the interpreter does, line by line:

```py
# First of all object creation is executed
a = Aave(1)

# This invokes method __init__ of class Aave, hence next step is 
a.address = 1

# After the creation of a class instance, interpreter tries to run
print(a.function_map())

# But since value of a.function_map() is unknown it needs to be calculated first
# Hence, interpreter enters function_map method of class Aave
# Execution of
mapping = {1:self.test(), 2:self.test2()}
# requires the test() and test2() to be evaluated. Since brackets indicate function call

# Thus, test() runs, prints 1 and returns 1. If we could see the value of 
# mapping after this, it would have been:
# {1: 1, 2: <unknown yet result of self.test2()>}
#     ^
# This value is the result of self.test()

# Next self.test2() is evaluated, since it also has brackets and needs to be called
# test2() runs, prints 2 and returns 2.
# After this step, mapping looks like {1: 1, 2: 2}
#                                         ^     ^
#                          Had this already     result of self.test2()

# After this mapping is completely known and next line may be evaluated.
# Evaluating 
print(type(self.test()))
# causes one more call to self.test, 
# since it also has brackets.

# And when you finally evaluate last line
return mapping[self.address]()
# Keeping in mind, that mapping was {1: 1, 2: 2}, you try to take value by key 1 from mapping,
# which is 1 (int). And call it (since you put "()"). It causes error, because 1 int is not callable.
```

As a result, you have 2 calls to `self.test()` in lines

```py
mapping = {1:self.test(), 2:self.test2()}
# AND
print(type(self.test()))
```

and one call to `self.test2()` in line

```py
mapping = {1:self.test(), 2:self.test2()}
```

If you wanted to be able to call what you store in `mapping`, you would need to remove those brackets in `mapping` creation. This way you would store function-objects in a dict instead of function results.

```py
mapping = {1:self.test(), 2:self.test2()}  # Call functions and store results
# VS
mapping = {1:self.test, 2:self.test2}  # Store functions themselves
```

It's the whole difference. With brackets - result of function call, without - function-object.